# Action bar tabs and repeated background in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

Im aware of bug [Issue 15340: tilemode 'repeat' for bitmapdrawable does not work correctly always](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15340).

And I've successfully resolved it in Action bar by using `setBackgroundDrawable` method.

Unfortunately I don't have any method to set background on tabs.

Action bar in the upper top and three tabs:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change actionbar tabs background with [setStackedBackgroundDrawable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setStackedBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) method